# JAAS: How to load config file?

Tags: java, jaas

I'm trying to run the JAAS code sample.

```
lc = new LoginContext("JaasSample", new TextCallbackHandler());
```

To register the configuration file I try the command:

```
java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.config JaasAcn
```

And gets the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class .security.auth.login.config=jaas.config
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /security/auth/login/config=jaas/config

Comment: Please let me to write answer.
There are many mistakes in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) and I have two points:
Today java use "javax" library.
And prefer to use the programmicly way to set Configuration.

Comment: `java.security.auth.login.config` is not a package name. It is the name of a system property, and it is documented correctly. Your problem is due to a trivial typo: nothing else.

Comment: @EJP so which typo? And why the error is *class* not found?

Comment: This is already covered completely in my answer. You can't seriously expect me to state it all twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly write `javax` instead of `java`, so:

```
java -Djavax.security.auth.login.config=jaas.config JaasAcn
```

And second, consider to config it programmicly:

1. Inherit the `javax.security.auth.login.Configuration` class.
2. Override the function `AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name)`. In this func you can return an `AppConfigurationEntry` object that represent a row in [config file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html).

   ```
   new AppConfigurationEntry(NTLoginModule.class.getName(),
   AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, new HashMap<>())
   ```

   With `name` parameter you can responde for the `name` parameter in `LoginContext` constructor.
3. Create object from your Configuration class and put him in Configuration:

   ```
   MyConfiguration config = new MyConfiguration();
   Configuration.setConfiguration(config);
   ```

The shortened code can look like this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration() {
    @Override
    public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
        return new AppConfigurationEntry[]{
                new AppConfigurationEntry(NTLoginModule.class.getName(),
                    AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
                    new HashMap<>())
        };
    }
};
Configuration.setConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: The name of the system property is `java.security.auth.login.config`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html#Policy). No `javax` in there. Nothing here that identifies the actual problem.

Comment: @EJP if the question is "how to config" so the programmicly way is not answer?

Comment: And with javax I'm not getting a "class not found" error

Comment: The question is why the class not found error, and `javax` is still wrong, and you won't get a 'class not found error' with `java` if you type it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a typo in the command line: a space after `-Djava`, so the `.security.auth.login.config=jaas.config` part is taken as the class name (and hence also mangled accordingly).

Comment: i get the same error ```Error: Could not find or load main class .security.auth.login.config=``` and i have no typo there

Comment: Of course you do. Something is separating `-Djava` from `.security.auth.login.config`.

Comment: well it turned out not. simply the command line config arguments were like this. no matter which one i picked (or copy pasted), it always wanted to find the class ```.someclass...```.
i ended up setting these preferences directly in the code via: ```System.setProperty("-Djavax.security.auth.login.config", "value");```